# STL SET Iterator assignment no viable candidate

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have a C++ program using an STL Set with an iterator. The set and iterator are defined as:

```
 set<TokenTableEntry*, Comparator> _XCLITokenTable;

 set<TokenTableEntry*>::const_iterator it;
```

I have a routine called findToken (shown below), that has a statement:

```
 it = _XCLITokenTable.find(_TokenTableEntry);
```

Which is producing the error message:

> "implicit std::_Tree
>   std::less,std::allocator,0>>::const_iterator::operator=(const                                 std::_Tree,std::allocator,0>>::const_iterator &)" is not a viable candidate.

I have no idea what this message is telling me or how to correct it. Can anyone make a suggestion?

Thanks for any help.

John

```
int XCLITokenTable::findToken (string name,  TokenTableEntry *_TokenTableEntry) 
{

    int type;
    type = -1;

    string lookupName(name);

    std::transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), ::tolower);

    _TokenTableEntry->name = lookupName;

    **it = _XCLITokenTable.find(_TokenTableEntry);**

    if (it != _XCLITokenTable.end())
    {
        if ((*it)->name == name)
        {
            type = (*it)->type;
            tokenCount++;
            *_TokenTableEntry = *(*it);
            return type;
        }

    }
    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `it` as

```
set<TokenTableEntry*, Comparator>::const_iterator it;
```

Or you can use `auto` if C++11 is available:

```
auto it = _XCLITokenTable.find(_TokenTableEntry);
```

(and preferrably declare `int XCLITokenTable::findToken(...) const`, so the return type of `find` will be `const_iterator`)

Comment: Wow! I  worked on that for hours and got nowhere. You're solution was 100% correct. Thank you very much.